# Dynamic Query in a MS-Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in Microsoft Access (2016) where I have a dropdown list named KID. When the dropdown list looses Focus I want to run a query that would look like this:

```
SELECT max(Cnt)
FROM Table
WHERE KID = ValueOfDropdownList
```

The result of this query should be usable in a variable in the VB Code of the Event.

Unfortuantly I am restricted to Access at the Moment. Am I even using Access the right way (Choose from dropdown in form -> Event -> SQL Query in VB -> Display in form) or are there better ways to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would use the `AfterUpdate` event of the combo box, otherwise it will fire even if someone just tabs through the control.

Secondly if this is just to set a variable you would probably be better to use a Domain function in this case a DMax()

```
iVariable = DMax("Cnt","Table","[KID] = " & Me.YourComboControlName )
```

This assumes KID is a number field. If KID is text you would need to delimit the criteria like this;

```
 iVariable = DMax("Cnt","Table","[KID] = '" & Me.YourComboControlName & "'" )
```

Lastly if you want this to update as you scroll through records you would need to add the same code to the `OnCurrent` event of the form. That fires when the record changes.

If it is for display purposes you can't use the same technique on a continuous form if this is setting an Unbound control, you would need to pull this in to the underlying forms recordset.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my first question on Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DMax*:

```
YourVariable = DMax("[Cnt]", "[Table]", "[KID] = " & Me!DropdownListName.Value & "")
```

In case KID is text, apply quotes:

```
YourVariable = DMax("[Cnt]", "[Table]", "[KID] = '" & Me!DropdownListName.Value & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is another option. As the `data source` of your combo,
use a query returning 2 columns, like `select KID, max(cnt) from table1 group by KID`.
Then in your text box, retrieve your value using `=combo1.columns(1)`.
For this to work you need to specify in the combo properties that it has 2 columns. In the formula, don't forget that those combo columns are 0 based.
This is the most efficient solution when you need to retrieve several values linked to the combo (and you don't have millions of records).